# How to Compare data of specific columns in multiple selected rows ( myGrid rows) in javascript

Tags: javascript, html, css

How to Compare data of specific columns in multiple selected rows ( myGrid rows) in JavaScript.

In myGrid every row contains checkbox.
when user have select check box (onCheckbox function will call), i would like to compare some specific column data must be same for all selected row. 
when user deselected all rows no need to compare.
Again user will be select one by one rows and same specific column data compare, if same specific column data equal then row will selected else deselected...

i.e specific column is A,B,C (when user selecte oncheckbox, A,B,C data will be same for all selecte row then it will geting selected )
My grid contains column A,B,C,D,E
user will select row 1 that time need not check anything.
row 1 data contains  a,b,c,d,r,e
user select row 2 it will compare row 1 A,B,C column date with row 2 A,B,C column data if same it allows to select row 2 with row 1 else not allows to select.
row 2 data contains  a1,b1,c1,d1,e1
row 2 data contains  a,b,c,d2,e2

Comment: You need to share relevant code i.e. HTML and JavaScript both. Otherwise question is too broad and might be closed.

Comment: @Satpal we will wants to compare row-1 columns A,B and C with Row-2 Columns A,B and C is equal or not in side myGrid.attachEvent("onCheckbox" ,function(rid,ind,stage){ });